# Concatenation of pd.Series results in pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I don't get why my code doesn't work.

If I execute the code below I get the following error:

> pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.

The created series have all a timestamp index, where some entries are the same. I don't understand what the difference to the example from the pandas [manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes) is, 
because the indices of the dfs have also identical indices.

```py
ds = pd.Series([dat[1] for dat in dic_data[name]], index=[dat[0] for dat in dic_data[name]], name=name) # create the series
ds_list.append(ds)


df = pd.concat(ds_list,axis=1,sort=False) # i copyed this line from the example, from the pandas manual
```

the resulting dataframe should be created like the one from the example 
[pics](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `dic_data` ?

Comment: this is the structure of dic_data = {'col_name_1':[(timestamp_1,vlaue_1,),....,(timestamp_n,value_n,)] }

Answer (score 0):

In the example by pandas you can have a `pandas.Series` which has the same or similar index values as another which you intend to concatenate. However each `pandas.Series` index values have to be unique.

i.e. `len(ds.index) - len(ds.index.unique())` *should equal 0*

Your index in `ds` has multiple values that are the same. 
If you want to concatenate based on the `index`, it is unclear how to combine these indices with another `pandas.Series`, so you will recieve an error.

For example your code will work if each `ds` has an index which is unique.

```
ds_list = []
dates =  pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', periods=7); values = np.arange(7)
dic_data = {'Col1' : [(dates[i], values[i]) for i in range(7)], 'Col2' : [(dates[i], values[i]*2) for i in range(7)]}
for name in dic_data.keys():
    ds = pd.Series([dat[1] for dat in dic_data[name]], index=[dat[0] for dat in dic_data[name]], name=name)
    ds_list.append(ds)

df = pd.concat(ds_list,axis=1,sort=False)
```

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
            Col1  Col2
2019-01-01     0     0
2019-01-02     1     2
2019-01-03     2     4
2019-01-04     3     6
2019-01-05     4     8
2019-01-06     5    10
2019-01-07     6    12
```

However if your `ds` has duplicated index values it will not:

```
dic_data = {'Col1' : [(dates[i % 7], values[i % 7]) for i in range(12)], 'Col2' : [(dates[i], values[i]*2) for i in range(7)]}
for name in dic_data.keys():
    ds = pd.Series([dat[1] for dat in dic_data[name]], index=[dat[0] for dat in dic_data[name]], name=name)
    ds_list.append(ds)

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

As a fix I would aggregate on timestamps by for example doing a `groupby` or however you want to aggregate on these duplicates:

```
dic_data = {'Col1' : [(dates[i % 7], values[i % 7]) for i in range(12)], 'Col2' : [(dates[i], values[i]*2) for i in range(7)]}
for name in dic_data.keys():
    ds = pd.Series([dat[1] for dat in dic_data[name]], index=[dat[0] for dat in dic_data[name]], name=name)
    ds = ds.groupby(level=0).sum()
    ds_list.append(ds)
```

Or you could just drop duplicates, e.g. `ds.drop_duplicates()` ...